# Warning while using Select component without any value

Tags: reactjs, controlled-component

I have `<InputLabel>` and `Select` and `MenuItem` components used in the code as follows:

```
<div className="form-field full-width-field ">
                   
                    <InputLabel>Q3.Is this the correct data?</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        value={''}
                       onChange={handleChange}
                        >
                        <MenuItem value={'Y'}>Yes</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={'N'}>No</MenuItem>
                        
                        </Select>
                    </div>
```

So, when I use `value = {''}` as shown above in the `Select`, I don't see any error in the code. However, when a user selects `Yes` or `No`, nothing is displayed on the screen, as shown below:

[image]

However, when I comment out the `value = {''}`  part and use it like this:

```
                     <Select
                        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                        id="demo-simple-select"
                        //value={''}
                       onChange={handleChange}
                        >
```

It displays the user selection `Yes` or `No` on the screen but I keep getting following warning  in the console i nred color:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type
> undefined to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from
> uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a
> controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the
> component.

How can I fix both the issues?

Comment: Use `defaultValue` attribute instead of `value` attribute. Read more here - https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 0):

Make your component controlled.

```
const [answer, setAnswer] = useState('');

function handleChange(event) {
    setAnswer(event.target.value);
}

<div className="form-field full-width-field ">
    <InputLabel>Q3.Is this the correct data?</InputLabel>
    <Select labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={answer}
            onChange={handleChange}>
        <MenuItem value={'Y'}>Yes</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={'N'}>No</MenuItem>                        
    </Select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. Quick question - I have couple of more dropdown similar to what I showed in my post. Would you recommend me to define two more `userState('')` for other two dropdowns as well? For example - `const [answer1, setAnswer1] = useState('');`  & `const [answer2, setAnswer2] = useState('');` ?

Comment: @Tan yes if you have a kind of form I would recommend to define state for every field. This is a way haw controlled inputs work in React